# HTML : How to pass value of textbox using hyperlink?

Tags: html

I have an php  page that displays the values . I want to use  hyperlink rather than a button. What I want to happen is that the user will update the values  from the textbox then click on a "Go"  . My problem is I don't know how to pass the value of the textbox using a hyperlink. Can somebody please help me?

Thank you For all .

for example :

```
<form action="" method= "post">
First name :<input type="text" name ="fname"/>"
  <a href="" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to update information?')">Update</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to post `form` on click `hyperlink`

Comment: why use a link instead of a submit? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this:

```
<form action="" method= "post">
    First name :<input type="text" name ="fname"/>"
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

And use CSS to display the input as a hyperlink

```
form input[type="submit"] {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You could also use Javascript to have the `<a>` submit the form, I think this way is easier though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the `submit()` method of the FormElement in JavaScript to submit the form without a regular submit button, if you really want to use a hyperlink.

Example from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit):

```
document.forms["myform"].submit()
```

If you want to do it all in your `onclick` handler (which is typically considered bad practice), then you can give your `<form>` an `id` and call it all at once like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirm('Do you really want to update information?')&&document.getElementById('myform').submit()">
    Update
</a>
```

However, it is probably best to stick with a submit button to provide better browser/client support and to be more semantically correct. If you want the button to look like a link, it would be better to use CSS to make it appear the way you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful:

```
<form action="test.php" id="myForm" method= "post" onsubmit="if( confirm('Do you really want to update information?')) {this.submit();}">
First name :<input type="text" name ="fname" id="fname"/>
  <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit();">Update</a>
</form>
```